# How to create table of content from markdown content in NextJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I created a blog detail page in NextJS, where blog content is markdown.

```
import { serialize } from "next-mdx-remote/serialize";
import { MDXRemote } from "next-mdx-remote";

const PostDetails = ({ post, source }) => {
  const router = useRouter();

  if (router.isFallback) {
    return <Loader />;
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>Basir - Blogs</title>
      </Head>
      <div className="container mx-auto px-4 lg:px-6 my-24">
        <div className="max-w-4xl px-4 lg:px-8 mx-auto">
          <PostDetail post={post} />

          <div className="prose">
            <MDXRemote {...source} />
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
export default PostDetails;

export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  
  const data = await getPostDetails(params.slug);
  const mdxSource = await serialize(data.content);

  return {
    props: {
      post: data,
      source: mdxSource
    },
  };
}


export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const posts = await getPosts();
  return {
    paths: posts.map(({ node: { slug } }) => ({ params: { slug } })),
    fallback: true,
  };
}
```

How do I create a table of content for the above blog detail page with clickable links that navigates the user to the respective blog heading?